# Two-pane outliner / note-taking application, WYSIWYG, Windows, gratis or open source

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, note-taking

I'm looking for an outliner / note-taking application, which is actively supported.

I'd like to find features as:

- Two-pane view, with an outline tree and the document
- Documents as WYSIWYG, with the inclusion of images and syntax-highlighted text
- Running on Windows
- Having some export function (...), like HTML/PDF/... for formatted document sharing
- Free or open sourced

I've already evaluated many applications over the years, but I hardly find something that looks like a modernized KeyNote NF, with a *consistent* and *uncluttered* interface or a footprint below 100 MiB (...)

*(similar to **KeyNote NF** (or CherryTree))*